# Date Regex works in prod but not on my local

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, date

We're using the below regex to validate a date.  It works fine in prod, and also on other developers' machines, but it's failing on mine.  My culture is the same as the rest of the team: "en-us".

I'm baffled.  What should I look at?

This is with an ASP.NET MVC stack.

Regex:

```
@"^__/__/____|(?=\d)^(?:(?!(?:10\D(?:0?[5-9]|1[0-4])\D(?:1582))|(?:0?9\D(?:0?[3-9]|1[0-3])\D(?:1752)))((?:0?[13578]|1[02])|(?:0?[469]|11)(?!\/31)(?!-31)(?!\.31)|(?:0?2(?=.?(?:(?:29.(?!000[04]|(?:(?:1[^0-6]|[2468][^048]|[3579][^26])00))(?:(?:(?:\d\d)(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])(?!\x20BC))|(?:00(?:42|3[0369]|2[147]|1[258]|09)\x20BC))))))|(?:0?2(?=.(?:(?:\d\D)|(?:[01]\d)|(?:2[0-8])))))([-.\/])(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\2(?!0000)((?=(?:00(?:4[0-5]|[0-3]?\d)\x20BC)|(?:\d{4}(?!\x20BC)))\d{4}(?:\x20BC)?)(?:$|(?=\x20\d)\x20))?((?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?::[0-5]\d){0,2}(?:\x20[aApP][mM]))|(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(?::[0-5]\d){1,2})?$"
```

Comment: OMG, this monster is the mother of all ugly regex-es! It's definitely a write-only regex, though.

Comment: I'm not sure that a regex is the right tool for this problem.

Comment: Email validation is always going to be impossible.  There.  I said it.

Comment: E-mail validation is totally possible... it just shouldn't be done with a regex, and many of the "rules" about e-mail addresses people think they know are imaginary.